# Scala will stack overflow in tail recursion without trampolines, which language manages this?

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming, stack-overflow

I'm studying functional programming using Scala, and came across this nice talk by Runar Bjarnason http://youtu.be/hzf3hTUKk8U?t=17m35s

Are there languages that already deal with this problem:

- tail recursion elimination (without using trampoline or other
  explicit construct) 
  I know that Scala can convert self call tail recursion to a loop, thus avoiding creation of stacks, but there are recursion that scala compiler does not accept @annotation.tailrec as presented on the clip at 3min - 7m.

The language sought after here is functional, has compile time type system, and has lazy evaluation.

When the above is answered, I check the question answered. But it would be nice to know if also the other language features presented by Bjarnason are managed already by some language:
 - kind reference
 - better type inference
 - unboxed function references

Comment: Haskell comes to mind.

Comment: Scala does handle direct tail recursion iteratively. But it does not do any other kind of tail-call optimization so mutually tail-recursive functions accumulate activation records.

Comment: it's not really opinion-based (apart from the 'better'). It's an objective question (does a language with those technical features exist).

Comment: @Paul well, then it will be closed with [more precise reason](http://take.ms/52goR)

Comment: Maybe. I still think it's not an unreasonable question. Not sure were it should be asked, though

Comment: Maybe the talk from which the question is based points too strongly to haskell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Scheme language (part of the lisp family) is guaranteed by the language specification to perform tail call optimization. However it doesn't have any of the nice language features you mention.

For a modern functional language with a powerful optimizing compiler (performs TCO and much more) with all the powerful language features you're asking for, I highly recommend [Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters)

Comment: Now that I watched the talk for the second time I guess Runar's point is to present Scalaists that Haskell has these 5 features that would be nice to have in Scala too. For me as a newbie to FB, the trampoline avoidance seemed to be a manageable feature provided by a language.